# When I trying to edit profiles in kivy designer it Shows error and close the kivy designer

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Kivy,kivy-designer.I want to execcute my app on android device but when I tried to do there's an error

```
error File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 278, in get_file_content
 raise InstallationError('Could not open requirements file: %s' % str(e))
 pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/desktop/kivy/musicplayer/designer/tools/../../requirements.txt'
```

When I click on edit profiles in run it close the kivy designer & shows above error.How do I solve this problem.